# Formdata not updating nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, multipartform-data, form-data

I am sending a patch request using axios that looks like this

```
const productData = new FormData();
    productData.append("ProductName", ProductName)
    productData.append("ProductCategory", ProductCategory)
    //productData.append("ProductImg", ProductImg, "ProductImg.jpg")
    for(var x = 0; x<ProductImg.length; x++) {
        productData.append('ProductImg', ProductImg[x])
    }
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:4500/products/${id}`, productData,
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("Authorization")
            }
        }
        )
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)

        })
        .catch(err =>
            console.log(`The error we're getting from the backend--->${err}`))
```

I am capturing the given data over a node express backend as follows

```
exports.products_update_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  const updateOps = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
    updateOps[key]= value
  }
  Product.update({ _id: id }, { $set: updateOps })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Product updated",
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

The problem I am facing here is the product does not get updated but returns 200 from the backend. I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(result) before you res.status

Comment: It returns { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } because when I console.log(req.body) on the backend, it is an empty object.

Comment: If your req.body is empty than thats why you are not updating anything so where ever you are sending the request from is probably where the error is.

Try console.log(productData) before you send the patch request and see what is there